# I'm like the hull of the sun. What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I'm like the hull of the sun.
>
> But I'm not a star.
>
> I start with a kernel
>
> And end like a keeper
>
> But without opposing directions

What am I?

### Hint

> I'm not a thing, I'm a person

### Edit

Changed the last line from `But only like so`. It is a more consistent part of the riddle now

Comment: Would it be too obvious if I said it was popcorn?

Comment: It's not that obvious

Comment: But popcorn is not that obvious. The only reference to popcorn would be kernel

Comment: Well the sunny nature suggested popcorn kernel and there is a suggestion of a transformation so my first instinct was popcorn but obviously it is more in-depth than that

Comment: ROT13(Havk-yvxr flfgrzf fghss? Fha, Xreary, Funerq Bowrpg...)

Comment: @문동선 Nothing to do with this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this answer might actually be

> Coroner

I'm like the hull of the sun.

> Sounds like corona, as found by jafe

But I'm not a star.

> Not usually famous.

I start with a kernel

> Core (also discovered by jafe)

And end like a keeper

> Owner

But without opposing directions

> Core + Owner = Coreowner = Coroner, when we remove E and W (East and West)

Obviously, jafe's answer filled in many of the lines so do upvote that answer too.

Answer (score 8):

Are you

> the footballer [Corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_(footballer))?

I'm like the hull of the sun.

> The outer part of the Sun and other stars is called the [corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona).

But I'm not a star.

> Not really a household name.

I start with a kernel

> cor(e)

And end like a keeper

> Not sure about this. There are certainly goalkeepers whose name rhymes with Corona, such as [Marafona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Carlos_Marafona)... Hard to believe this is what's intended here, though.

But without opposing directions

> No idea what this means yet...

Comment: You are on the right track

Comment: ohg vg'f abg n fcrpvsvp crefba